# Motherboard and chipset specifications disagree on memory support. Which to believe?

Tags: memory, motherboard, supermicro

I'd like to upgrade my ancient [Super Micro SuperServer 6024H-i](http://www.supermicro.com/products/system/2U/6024/SYS-6024H-i.cfm) with a little more memory. Its motherboard manual specifies support for DDR-233/300 memory only. However, it is equipped with an [Intel E7520 Lindenhurst chipset](http://ark.intel.com/products/27743/Intel-E7520-Memory-Controller), which specifies additional support for DDR2-400 memory.

Obviously, I'd hate to miss out on better performance if I can get it, but it seems unwise to ignore the manual. Which specification should I go by?

Comment: *"Which specification should I go by?"* -- The motherboard's, which is the implementation of the chipset.

Comment: Highest common dominator...

Comment: @woliveirajr. "Highest common ***dominator***". Made my day. ;D

Comment: Just another bit of caution. If your operating system is 32 bit, it is only capable of using 4gb Ram. More than that you will need to have a 64 bit operating system.

Comment: @Nolonar ops... but now I won't edit it :)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

DDR uses 2.5 Volts and has 184 pins

DDR2 uses 1.8 Volts and has 240 pins

The two are not compatible and require different sized slots.  Use the DDR.  They're the only one that fits yout motherboard.